# Can a Dragonborn with an Extra Attack use both their breath weapon and their melee attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, dragonborn

My Dragonborn character is about to get the Extra Attack ability and I'm curious if it can be used with the breath attack. Since a Dragonborn can only use the attack once per short rest I know he can't use it twice, but could he use his breath weapon and then make a melee attack?

I've only seen extra attacks used for the same weapon attacking twice for PCs so I'm not sure if a Dragonborn can use both their breath weapon and melee weapon as an extra attack.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, Extra Attack can only be used to attack. Extra Attack says:

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

Furthermore, the Dragonborn's Breath Weapon ability says:

> You can use your action to exhale destructive energy.

If Breath Weapon gave you, for example, a special ranged weapon you could use to make attacks with, this would work. But what it gives you is a special action. You can use that action to use your Breath Weapon, or you can use the Attack action. There's no way to do both with a single action.